# HTML date tag to MySql using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html

This question may have been answered with  This line of code.

I've searched a round and have not locate a usable answer to my issues.

I want to take a html  and use the value that creates and saved as $userDateCreated.  the value needs to be reformatted to match MySql So that i can utilize the date input tag in my form.

INSERT INTO `employee`.`details`(`userDateCreated`) VALUES ('$userDateCreated');

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly does your HTML date tag look like? How about its data; how's that represented? What HTML are you looking to create and save as `$userDateCreated`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML's input type date and MySQL's date type use the same format.

Comment: html 5 = dd/mm/yyyy    MySQL users yyyy/mm/dd

Comment: Nope. The actual value that is sent is in the yyyy-mm-dd format, the same format MySQL expects. Try it: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_date

Comment: thanks a lot. :) that totally tricked me

Answer (score -1):

Use strtotime() and date() to reformat the html5 date into your wished date.